# Change the source codebase eof master in github

Tags: git

I have created a private repository in github
I used clone the directory and push my code base initially.
Mistakenlly, I pushed wrong codebase, now I need to push another code in the master directory?

I tried to delete the files in the cloned folder and push the new one.  It doesn't push the code and throws error like as follows.
Please help me to resolve this:

```
git.exe push --progress  "origin" master:master

Counting objects: 274, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (254/254)
Writing objects: 100% (273/273), 173.91 MiB | 6.32 MiB/s
Writing objects: 100% (273/273), 181.78 MiB | 6.49 MiB/s, done.
Total 273 (delta 68), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200
Everything up-to-date
```

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply:

- make sure you have the correct history in your local repo
- make a:

  ```
  git push -f
  ```

That will force the push, erasing the history of the remote repo (which isn't bad, since you are the only one using it), and replacing it by the local repo history.

So if you have fixed your history locally, you can mirror it on your private GitHub repo with a `git push -f`.